# Como pasar 2 variables por AJAX hacia otro PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Bueno lo que quiero hacer es enviar 2 variables js con valor de un input por  AJAX hacia un archivo que las recibe como por ejemplo:  $_POST['idReceptor']. Si envió una sola variable se envia bien pero no puedo enviar 2.

```
var idEmisor = $("#idEmisor").val();
           var idReceptor = $("#idReceptor").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/chat/conversacion.php",
                data: {"idReceptor="+idReceptor, "idEmisor="+idEmisor}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad data de Ajax es un objeto JSON. En tu caso lo tienes mal escrito. Haz esto:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/chat/conversacion.php",
    data: { idReceptor, idEmisor }
    // esto es lo mismo que { idReceptor: idReceptor, idEmisor: idEmisor }
    ...
});
```

Así se enviarán correctamente.

Comment: Perfecto me estaba mareando era eso! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar datos Json para enviar tus parámetros; como te muestro a continuación:

```js
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/chat/conversacion.php',
            data: {idReceptor: idReceptor, idEmsiro: idEmisor },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                ...
            }
        });
```